# widow paragraph title with orphan epigraph with epigraph package

Tags: paragraphs, widows-orphans, epigraphs

When I use an `\epigraph{}` command (from the `epigraph` package) just after a paragraph containing a title, I can get a widow paragraph title on a page bottom and an orphan epigraph on the next page top… It’s ugly.

This is a minimal example code of this behaviour:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside,french]{article}
\usepackage{epigraph}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\widowpenalty=10000
\clubpenalty=10000
\raggedbottom

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-4]

\paragraph{lorem ipsum dolor}
\epigraph{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet}{Ciceron}

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

And this is the rendering of this code:
[image]

As you see, I use `\widowpenality`, but I can’t force the paragraph title to go to the next page instead of leave as a widow on the original page.

So, how can I force all paragraph’s titles to go to the next page to follow there epigraph?

Comment: Just use `\pagebreak`.

Comment: No, I will not use a `\pagebreak` before every paragraph. However, I use `\nopagebreak` between `\paragraph` and `\epigraph` but it doesn’t work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for this break between the `\paragraph` and `\epigraph` stems from the construction of the `\epigraph`: it uses skips before (and after) and lists to adjust the layout. You may be better suited writing your own `\epigraph`:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\raggedbottom

\newcommand{\epigraph}[2]{%
  \par\nobreak\noindent\par\nobreak\vspace{.5\baselineskip}
  \hfill{\small\begin{tabular}{@{}p{.4\textwidth}@{}}
    #1 \\[1ex]
    \hline
    \hfill #2
  \end{tabular}}
  \vspace{.5\baselineskip}
}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-4]

\paragraph{lorem ipsum dolor}
\epigraph{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet}{Ciceron}

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

The lengths used above are the typical defaults used by [`epigraph`](http://ctan.org/pkg/epigraph).

Answer (score 1):

You could load the `needspace` package and issue the instruction

```
\needspace{3\baselineskip}
```

immediately before the `\paragraph`/`\epigraph` combination in question.

---

The full MWE (the paragraph header and the epigraph will show up at the top of a page:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside,french]{article}
\usepackage{epigraph,lipsum}
\usepackage{needspace}

\widowpenalty=10000
\clubpenalty=10000
\raggedbottom

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-4]

\needspace{3\baselineskip}
\paragraph{lorem ipsum dolor}
\epigraph{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet}{Ciceron}

\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```